Error when login into publisher, admin or devportal
IM getting this error when i try to access publisher, admin portal o devportal login
`TID: [] [] [2024-09-18 12:18:31,806] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.common.jms.JMSListener} - JMS Provider is not yet started. Please start the JMS provider now.
TID: [] [] [2024-09-18 12:18:31,806] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.common.jms.JMSListener} - Connection attempt : 3 for JMS Provider failed. Next retry in 80 seconds
TID: [-1234] [publisher] [2024-09-18 12:20:21,437] ERROR {org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/publisher].[idp]} - Servlet.service() for servlet [idp] in context with path [/publisher] threw exception java.io.IOException: An exception occurred processing [/services/login/idp.jsp] at line [72]
 
69:     HttpRequest getSettingsReq = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
70:             .uri(URI.create(settingsAPIUrl))
71:             .build();
72:     HttpResponse<String> settingsResult = client.send(getSettingsReq, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
73: 
74:     HttpRequest getCatalogReq = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
75:             .uri(URI.create(serviceCatalogSettingsAPIUrl))
 
 
Stacktrace:
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:494)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:379)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException
Caused by: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException`

Any ideas what it could be? JMS service seems to do not start and then i get the above error.
I have fresh installed WSO2 as I always do, but i go this error.
